# Displaying graph plots with mouse click on map in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-addin

I need to build a tool/add-in for ArcGIS 10 which will display a time distribution plot at the location where mouse is clicked. The TOC consists of results of a simulation at different time instants. For the clicked point, the tool should read-in the output values at different time instants from TOC and plot it as a graph and show it as a pop-up.

So far, I have managed to draw the time distribution graphs for a set of points stored in a shapefile and save it to a working folder with a Python script but couldn't manage to get X,Y coordinates for the clicked point and enter it as input and then display the plot at the end. I have really no idea if Python supports mouse-click events like VB does.

If it is not possible with Python, which other language should I turn to (e.g., VB.net)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mouse events are supported in Python add-ins, check the `onMouseDown`, `onMouseDownMap`, `onMouseUp` and `onMouseUpMap` functions on the Python addin [Tool class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/tool-class.htm) page.

For a practical example check also this Esri technical article: [How To: Capture map coordinates with a mouse click using Python](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011690)

Comment: Thanks @GISGe for your answer...I will go through Python add-ins and figure out how to do it...And how will I manage graph in a pop-up? With a messagebox?

Comment: I thought you had completed this part. What about the Make Graph tool? If you use it in ArcMap it should display the graph as a popup.

Comment: never used the Make Graph tool....I've used matplotlib in python to plot the graphs...I wonder if a msgbox can output the created graphs....Thanks for your hint though...

Comment: @ShS you can't use a msgbox. Use `arcpy.Graph()` and the `arcpy.MakeGraph_management` tool.